# Webview injection javascript

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, webview, code-injection

i have a webview window called blooket, whose code is the following: `import webview ;webview.create_window("Blooket", "https://play.blooket.com/play",width=800, height=600, resizable=True, fullscreen=False);webview.start(debug=True)`. How can i insert javascript code into this window so it supports userscripts?